# java regular expression to extract content within square brackets

Tags: java, regex

input line is below

```
Item(s): [item1.test],[item2.qa],[item3.production]
```

Can you help me write a Java regular expression to extract

```
item1.test,item2.qa,item3.production
```

from above input line?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

A bit more concise:

```
String in = "Item(s): [item1.test],[item2.qa],[item3.production]";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(in);

while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what the pattern means? Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You should use a positive lookahead and lookbehind:

```
(?<=\[)([^\]]+)(?=\])
```

- (?<=[) Matches everything followed by [
- ([^]]+) Matches any string not containing ]
- (?=]) Matches everything before ]

Comment: Awesome, but how can I get the opposite result? I want preserver only the content inside square brackets

Comment: I don't understand your question  - that's exactly what this regexp does.
Taking input 
`Item(s): [item1.test],[item2.qa],[item3.production]`
it returns
`item1.test`
`item2.qa`
`item3.production`

Answer (score 2):

I would split after trimming preceding or trailing junk:

```
String s = "Item(s): [item1.test], [item2.qa],[item3.production] ";
String r1 = "(^.*?\\[|\\]\\s*$)", r2 = "\\]\\s*,\\s*\\[";
String[] ss = s.replaceAll(r1,"").split(r2);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ss));
// [item1.test, item2.qa, item3.production]
```

Comment: @Stephan Kristyn: works for me on Java 1.6 on Mac OS X 10.6.7.

Comment: This is perfect, it avoids stackoverflow error as well for long string (where other solution fails)