# Get all text between { and } (source text contains \n)

Tags: java, android, regex

Consider the source text

```
{
a1
a2
a3
}
{
b1
b2
b3
}
```

I need to get 2 items:

```
a1
a2
a3
```

and

```
b1
b2
b3
```

using regular expression.

I tryed a solution like this:

[java regular expression to extract content within square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006113/java-regular-expression-to-extract-content-within-square-brackets)

but with no succes because the original text contains the '\n' character.

Comment: Use `[^}]` instead of `.*?`. I.e. `\\{([^}])\\}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could perhaps use this regex:

```
\\{\\n([^\\}]+)\\n\\}
```

Tested [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/wW5cS6).

[image: Regular expression image]

If you want the whole code, where `s` is what contains your source text:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\n([^\\}]+)\\n\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: Good! Should I use .split() function in Java to get correct results?

Comment: @Seraphim I added the code part in my answer. I'm not too familiar with the language of Java (regex is kind of a language of its own across many different languages), but I think that this would do.