# Java 1.4 sub string retreival

Tags: java, substring, java1.4

I have a string:

```
     thorax1  [00400 - 00479]
    su  [00100 - 0022200su]
    head1  [00100 - 00228]
    head1  [00100 - 00228]
    thorax1  [00400 - 00479]
    lab66  [lab661]
```

this can be big also. I need to retrieve the value that is there is in square bracket,

i.e. 00400 - 00479, 00100 - 0022200su ,00100 - 00228

I have used:

```
String Lab1=thorax1  [00400 - 00479]
su  [00100 - 0022200su]
head1  [00100 - 00228]
head1  [00100 - 00228]
thorax1  [00400 - 00479]
lab66  [lab661]

Lab1=    Lab.substring(Lab.indexOf("[")+1,Lab.indexOf("]"));
```

but this is only giving me `00400 - 00479`

I need the output like `00400 - 00479, 00100 - 0022200su ,00100 - 00228  and so on.`

Can anyone help me to get the desire output?

Comment: its a very old project .

Comment: "*its a very old project*" which doesn't automatically mean it has to be run only on old Java virtual machine. Anyway `substring(int start, int end)` returns **one** string including all character from position `start` (inclusive) till position `end` (exclusive). You should consider using loops to create more results and start looking for next `[` and `]` after last position they ware found. Consider using `indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)` or regex using `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes.

Comment: Take a look at [java-regular-expression-to-extract-content-within-square-brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006113/java-regular-expression-to-extract-content-within-square-brackets)

Comment: Use a `Matcher`, with a regular expression like `"\\[([^]]+)\\]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that what you are trying to do works only once. You need to place that logic (and add some more) into a loop.

This should do what you need:

```
String Lab = "thorax1  [00400 - 00479]"
                + "su  [00100 - 0022200su] "
                + "head1  [00100 - 00228] "
                + "head1  [00100 - 00228] "
                + "thorax1  [00400 - 00479] " +
                    "lab66  [lab661]";


        int first = 0;
    int last = 0;
    while(true)
    {   
        first = Lab.indexOf("[", first) + 1;
        last = Lab.indexOf("]", first);
        if(first <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(Lab.substring(first, last));
    }
```

Yields:

```
00400 - 00479
00100 - 0022200su
00100 - 00228
00100 - 00228
00400 - 00479
lab661
```

Comment: This is giving the output , but I need the output in a single string with comma separator. :(

Comment: @Suman then you could use this same basic algorithm, but `append` each substring into a `StringBuilder` instead of printing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting the string and adding each individual part to an array of ArrayList,
then loop through it.