# Extracting string from within round brackets in Java with regex

Tags: java, regex, brackets

I'm trying to extract a string from round brackets.
Let's say, I have `John Doe (123456789)` and I want to output the string `123456789` only.

I have found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006113/java-regular-expression-to-extract-content-within-square-brackets) and this regex:

```
/\(([^)]+)\)/g
```

However, I wasn't able to figure out how to get the wanted result.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is your input and output? The referenced post shows how to get the Group 1 value.

Comment: Input is a String and output is also a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String str="John Doe (123456789)";
System.out.println(str.substring(str.indexOf("(")+1,str.indexOf(")")));
```

Here I'm performing string operations. I'm not that much familiar with regex.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me :

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    String test = "test (mytest)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);

    while(m.find()) {
        assertEquals("mytest", m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you need to use

```
String pattern = "\\(([^()]+)\\)";
```

Then, the value you need is in `.group(1)`.

```
String str = "John Doe (123456789)";
String rx = "\\(([^()]+)\\)";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

See  [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/PjVBNz)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape brackets in your regexp:

```
    String in = "John Doe (123456789)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d*)\\)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```