# How can I use a regular expression to match "aas" in this string?

Tags: java, regex

```
String str = "aa(aaq(aas)ppp)eeews";
```

How can I use a regular expression to match `"aas"`?

want to match the contents of the brackets, but not sure how many brackets,may be more and more

Comment: It is really easy. Have you tried anything? There are answers to it here, just search.

Comment: You need to provide more context. Is the number of `(` and `)` fixed or variable? What is it that makes `aas` rather than any of the others the thing to pick out? That it doesn't have any `(` or `)` in it? What about `aa` or `aaq`, why wouldn't we match them? Etc. Also indicate what you've tried and where you've gotten stuck. Show your attempts.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? If you want to get aas, you can simply put "aas" in a string... What other variations can there be of this string? Is aas always aas?

Comment: just wanna match the contents of the brackets, but not sure how many brackets,may be more..

Comment: So what if you have a string like this: `"(aa(aas)(aaf)www)"`? What result should this return?

Comment: The solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475386/extracting-string-from-within-round-brackets-in-java-with-regex/31475446#31475446). No idea who decided to reopen the question.

Comment: @stribizhev, it's not. Check out what that regex [matches](https://regex101.com/r/lF7sI1/1).

Comment: Now, I just added the `(`. It is the same question.

Comment: @stribizhev, now it's the same answer, but the question is different. :)

Comment: ok, then you make me post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to match the text inside parentheses that has no `(` or `)` inside, you can use

```
String str = "aa(aaq(aas)ppp)eeews";
String rx = "\\(([^()]*)\\)";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1)); // => aas
}
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fD7bJ2/1)

The text you need is in Capture group 1. See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/oCmqcN). To only get the first occurrence, use `if` instead of `while`.

Another way to get the first occurrence is with `"aa(aaq(aas)ppp)eeews".replaceAll("(?s).*?\\(([^()]*)\\).*$", "$1")` ([demo](http://ideone.com/lE6mrg)).

Why not use lookarounds? You can, but they always involve some additional overhead to the regex engine. Certainly, with this basic pattern as here, performance is not the key, however, it is best practice to only use lookarounds when you have to.

The regex details:

- `\(` - matches an opening `(`
- `([^()]*)` - Capture group 1 matching zero or more characters other than `(` or `)`
- `\)` - matches closing round bracket.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\\()[^()]*(?=\\))
```

- `(?<=\\()` - positive lookbehind to check for the existence of a opening bracket
- `[^()]` - a character, which is not a closing or opening bracket. You don't want closing brackets so you don't match more than you need. You don't want opening brackets, because you wanted the inner most.
- `*` - repeat the above zero or more times
- `(?=\\))` - positive lookahead to check for the existence of a closing bracket