# use regex in String.Split() for extract text between { and } in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
String str = ${farsiName} - {symbolName}
```

I want to use split method to find and extract ***farsiName*** & ***symbolName*** from this string with regex.
I found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/4006273/2670847 for doing something like this:

```
String in = "Item(s): [item1.test],[item2.qa],[item3.production]";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(in);

while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

But I want to know, can I use similar regex for split method in String class?

Comment: Yes you can use the same logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on right track. Just replace the brackets and string.

```
String n ="${farsiName} - {symbolName}";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*?)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(n);

while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I do this; but I'm looking for same way on split method.

Comment: @GLinBoy why do you want to that ? This is a perfect solution as well.

Comment: @Shashwat Out of curiosity!

Comment: @GLinBoy posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** : I do not recommend this. A regex would be much more versatile, and powerful.

```
String n ="${farsiName} - {symbolName}";
String s[] = n.split(" - ");
for(String x : s){
    System.out.println(x.replace("$", "").replace("{", "").replace("}", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String n ="${farstName} - {symbolName}";
    String arr[] = n.split(" - ");
    for(String s : arr){
        System.out.println(s.replace("$", "").replace("{", "").replace("}", ""));
    }
}
```

Use this code.It will work.But I recommend regex.