# How to convert a String which looks like an Array into an actual Object Array?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, reflection

Since

```
public static String requestMethodExecution(String objectName, String className, String methodName, Object...
            params) {
        return String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s", objectName, className, methodName, Arrays.toString(params));
    }
```

returns a String, and if you would, for example, call the method like this:

```
requestMethodExecution("foo","bar","fooBar",2.0,3.0,"Hello");
```

You'd get a String like this: `foo,bar,fooBar,[2.0,3.0,Hello]`

I would love to iterate over that Array, but I can't since it is a String.

Reason behind this is this method: (I just started with reflection, so I do not know how else to do it)

```
 public static Class[] getParameterType(String ...params) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            Class[] paramTypes = new Class[params.length];
            for(int i=0; i<params.length;i++){
                Class paramClass = Class.forName(params[i]);
                if (paramClass == Double.class) {
                    paramTypes[i] = (double.class);
                } else if (paramClass == Integer.class) {
                    paramTypes[i] = (int.class);
                } else {
                    paramTypes[i] = paramClass;
                }
            }
            return paramTypes;
    }
```

So far I have only come up with a very dirty way:

```
 public static String[] getParams(String message){
    int indexOfParamStart = message.indexOf("[");
    int indexOfParamEnd = message.indexOf("]")+1;
    String[] splitMessage = message.substring(indexOfParamStart, indexOfParamEnd).replaceAll("\\[", "")
            .replaceAll("]", "").replaceAll(" ","").split(",");
    return splitMessage;
}
```

Edit: Thanks for looking into this! Since some of you are asking what I am trying to achieve, here is a bit more explanation:

I want to implement a simple request/reply protocol which allows remote method invocation (and I do not want to use java RMI...)
So I listen for requests whose structure can be seen at the `requestMethodExecution` example.

There I have all the relevant information to call the Method upon my class, so to invoke the method I need it's arguments (and their value) and I do not know how to access them from the given String.

The others are easy with Class c = Class.forName(className); etc..

Edit#2:
My question is not about a simple regex, so why close it? The title already states a different subject, I am getting a bit salty here...

Comment: You'd have to parse it. It's not clear what problem you're actually trying to solve, though, since you already have an object array. What's the ultimate goal?

Comment: What do you mean by "you already have an object array". How do I iterate over that array/access it. To me it seems I just have a String which looks like an Object Array

Comment: What if your input contains a string with `,` in it? How would it look like?

Comment: This is a very good question and tbh I have no idea how to deal with that.

Comment: @InDaPond Can't you use some well-known syntax like JSON?

Comment: I could, but that would be over the top for the scope of this project, It will be used once and then never again..

Comment: You should think of it the other way. Inventing and parsing your own grammar is over the top.

Comment: I reopened your question (undoing the duplicate), but you need to work on clarifying and narrowing your question down or else it will likely get closed again as being too broad. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Are you basically asking about parsing actual argument values from the `String`? If that's the case, then you should revise the question text to make that more clear rather than appending extra stuff to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

See this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006113/java-regular-expression-to-extract-content-within-square-brackets%20this) question for using RegEx to extract the array body from the outer string (by the square brackets), and then you can simply use `String.split(",")` to split the array body into array items.