# Read username from log file using java

Tags: java, regex

I want to read username who logged in successfully through SSO and non-sso from log file. I think regular expression would help to achieve, but i need some directions to construct regex.

Input line to read from log:

```
    12:59:39.924 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-87] INFO  AuthenticationStrategy - Authentication for username [user1] & realm [SSORealm] successful.
    13:21:38.017 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-87] INFO  AuthenticationStrategy - Authentication for username [user2] & realm [Realm] successful.
    13:19:30.419 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-87] INFO  AuthenticationStrategy - Authentication for username [user1] & realm [LdapRealm] failed.
```

**Note: I want to read username who successfully logged in because there will some authentication failure as well and don't want to read those names.**

Expected output:

```
user1
user2
```

Sample Code which tried to read log file:

```
public class Log {
public static void main(String as[])
{
    try{
           FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\test.log");
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
           String strLine;
           while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
              System.out.println (strLine);
           }
           fstream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
}
}
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006113/java-regular-expression-to-extract-content-within-square-brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be an option to look at too:

```
(?m)(?<=username\\s\\[)[^\\r\\n\\]]+
```

---

If you wish to exclude the `failed` ones, we can add a negative lookahead, such as with:

```
(?m)(?!.*\\bfailed)(?<=username\\s\\[)[^\\r\\n\\]]+
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8bQhdv/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "(?m)(?!.*\\bfailed)(?<=username\\s\\[)[^\\r\\n\\]]+";
        final String string = "    12:59:39.924 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-87] INFO  AuthenticationStrategy - Authentication for username [user1] & realm [SSORealm] successful.\n"
             + "    13:21:38.017 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-87] INFO  AuthenticationStrategy - Authentication for username [user2] & realm [Realm] successful.\n"
             + "    13:19:30.419 [ajp-nio-0.0.0.0-8009-exec-87] INFO  AuthenticationStrategy - Authentication for username [user1] & realm [LdapRealm] failed.\n"
             + "N";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: user1
Full match: user2
```

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jdJTFm/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/jdJTFm/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression in order to get the user name of each line:

```
String input = "12:59:39.924 INFO  AuthenticationStrategy - Authentication for username [user1] & realm [SSORealm] successful.";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(" (\\[.*?\\])").matcher(input);
if (matcher.find(1)) {
    String userName = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(userName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just updated question with scenario that option to fail authentication also if square bracket before user name it won't  read.